# Script always gets a 302 response when pulling random pages from Wikipedia

Tags: python, http, wikipedia

I can pull a any page from wikipedia with

```
import httplib
conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("en.wikipedia.org")
conn.debuglevel = 1
conn.request("GET","/wiki/Normal_Distribution",headers={'User-Agent':'Python httplib'})
r1 = conn.getresponse()
r1.read()
```

The normal response will be

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n'
header: Date: Sun, 03 Apr 2011 23:49:36 GMT
header: Server: Apache
header: Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Content-Language: en
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
header: Last-Modified: Sun, 03 Apr 2011 17:23:50 GMT
header: Content-Length: 263638
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
header: Age: 1280309
header: X-Cache: HIT from sq77.wikimedia.org
header: X-Cache-Lookup: HIT from sq77.wikimedia.org:3128
header: X-Cache: MISS from sq66.wikimedia.org
header: X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq66.wikimedia.org:80
header: Connection: close
```

But if I try to pull a random page with /wiki/Special:Random I get a 302 response and an empty page

```
reply: 'HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily\r\n'
header: Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2011 19:25:52 GMT
header: Server: Apache
header: Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0, max-age=0, must-revalidate
header: Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
header: Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
header: Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuticorin_Port_Trust
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
header: X-Cache: MISS from sq60.wikimedia.org
header: X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq60.wikimedia.org:3128
header: X-Cache: MISS from sq62.wikimedia.org
header: X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from sq62.wikimedia.org:80
header: Connection: close
```

How do I get a non-empty random page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 302 is a redirect.  It's telling you where to go in the following line:

```
header: Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tuticorin_port_trust
```

You just need to follow the redirect.

Answer (score 3):

When you're redirected the response object is going to have a code of 302 and the `geturl()` method will report the redirect URL.  Python's standard HTTP libraries make it non-trivial to handled redirects by default. Do yourself a favor, don't hassle with this stuff and use the 3rd party [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) library, which is a drop-in replacement for `urllib2`.

Using mechanize, your code would look like this:

```
import httplib
import mechanize

host = 'en.wikipedia.org'
path = '/wiki/Special:Random'
url = 'http://' + host + path # We have to pass a http:// url

# It still uses httplib.HTTPConnection, so we can debug
httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

request = mechanize.Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Python-mechanize'}) 
response = mechanize.urlopen(request)

print response.code
# => 200
print response.geturl()
# => 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faliszowice,_Lesser_Poland_Voivodeship'
data = response.read()
```

Answer (score 2):

HTTP code 302 means you are being redirected. If you look at the **Location** header, you will see where you should make your new request. Then you can make the request to that URL and you'll hopefully get a 200 on that page.

To clarify: You are being *requested* to retry the request elsewhere. That's why your client needs to make another request when it receives a 302. Wikipedia's random page apparently works by choosing a random page in its database, then returning a 302 response with the new page as the Location field. If you look at other 302 responses, I'm sure you'll see a different page in the Location field.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the location header:

> header: Location: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuticorin_Port_Trust

It says you should redirected to that page. Read that header and do another request to that page.