# download files with python (REST URL)

Tags: python, http, cookies, request, urllib

I am trying to write a script that will download a bunch files from a website that has REST URLs.

Here is the GET request:

```
GET /test/download/id/5774/format/testTitle HTTP/1.1
Host: testServer.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:23.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/23.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: __utma=11863783.1459862770.1379789243.1379789243.1379789243.1; __utmb=11863783.28.9.1379790533699; __utmc=11863783; __utmz=11863783.1379789243.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); PHPSESSID=fa844952890e9091d968c541caa6965f; loginremember=Qraoz3j%2BoWXxwqcJkgW9%2BfGFR0SDFLi1FLS7YVAfvbcd9GhX8zjw4u6plYFTACsRruZM4n%2FpX50%2BsjXW5v8vykKw2XNL0Vqo5syZKSDFSSX9mTFNd5KLpJV%2FFlYkCY4oi7Qyw%3D%3D; ma-refresh-storage=1; ma-pref=KLSFKJSJSD897897; skipPostLogin=0; pp-sid=hlh6hs1pnvuh571arl59t5pao0; __utmv=11863783.|1=MemberType=Yearly=1; nats_cookie=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.testServer.com%252F; nats=NDc1NzAzOjQ5MzoyNA%2C74%2C0%2C0%2C0; nats_sess=fe3f77e6e326eb8d18ef0111ab6f322e; __utma=163815075.1459708390.1379790355.1379790355.1379790355.1; __utmb=163815075.1.9.1379790485255; __utmc=163815075; __utmz=163815075.1379790355.1.1.utmcsr=ppp.contentdef.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/postlogin; unlockedNetworks=%5B%22rk%22%2C%22bz%22%2C%22wkd%22%5D
Connection: close
```

If the request is good, it will return a 302 response such as this one:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Sat, 21 Sep 2013 19:32:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
location: http://downloads.test.stuff.com/5774/stuff/picture.jpg?wed=20130921152237&wer=20130922153237&hash=0f20f4a6d0c9f1720b0b6
Vary: User-Agent,Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

What I need the script to do is check to see if it was a 302 response. If it is not, it will "pass", if it is, it will need to parse out the location parameter shown here:

```
location: http://downloads.test.stuff.com/5774/stuff/picture.jpg?wed=20130921152237&wer=20130922153237&hash=0f20f4a6d0c9f1720b0b6
```

Once I have the location parameter, I will have to make another GET request to download that file. I will also have to maintain the cookie for my session in order to download the file.

Can someone point me in the right direction for what library is best to use for this? I am having trouble finding out how to parse the 302 response and adding a cookie value like the one shown in my GET request above. I am sure there must be some library that can do all of this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib.request as ur
import urllib.error as ue

'''
Note that http.client.HTTPResponse.read([amt]) reads and returns the response body, or up to 
the next amt bytes. This is because there is no way for urlopen() to automatically determine 
the encoding of the byte stream it receives from the http server. 
'''

url = "http://www.example.org/images/{}.jpg"

dst = ""
arr = ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09"]
# arr = range(10,20)
try:
    for x in arr:
        print(str(x)+"). ".ljust(4),end="")
        hrio = ur.urlopen(url.format(x)) # HTTPResponse iterable object (returns the response header and body, together, as bytes)
        fh = open(dst+str(x)+".jpg","b+w")
        fh.write(hrio.read())
        fh.close()
        print("\t[REQUEST COMPLETE]\t\t<Error ~ [None]>")
except ue.URLError as e:
    print("\t[REQUEST INCOMPLETE]\t",end="")
    print("<Error ~ [{}]>".format(e))
```

Comment: You can use this python-3 script to download images from `http://www.example.org/images/01.jpg` to `http://www.example.org/images/09.jpg`.

Comment: That code will not work. You commented out the url variable which is not a REST style URL. It will not grab the response to parse out the location. It also doesn't download the file, it reads it.

Comment: Ofcourse, I commented out the variable! I already spoon fed the answer :| Now you want me to chew it too :D

Comment: That solution doesn't seem to work. Again, it goes back to the response. I need a way to parse the http response and not the page source. It's a REST style URL, not the type of URL in your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707984/script-always-gets-a-302-response-when-pulling-random-pages-from-wikipedia